# jqGrid Horizontal Scrollbar / gridwidth using mvc3 razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, jqgrid, scrollbar

Aplologies if this has been posted before somewhere, I cannot see a problem which describes this issue....

I'm using mvc3/razor with jqGrid, and it seems it is not calculating the width properly - It is cutting off the Last column.

Could anyone tell me why?

I am using an unchanged ui.jqgrid.css and and jQueryUI themeroller theme, if that makes a difference!

My Index.cshtml :

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
<div id="content">
    <div id="content-left">
        @Html.Partial("SearchPanel")
    </div>
    <div id="content-main">
        <table id="jpgCustomers" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"></table>
        <div id="jpgpCustomers" style="text-align:center;"></div>
        <div id="dlgCustomer"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="CustomerEdit"></div>
@section JavaScript 
{
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () 
    {
        $('#jpgCustomers').jqGrid({
            //url from wich data should be requested
            url: '@Url.Action("Customers")',
            //type of data
            datatype: 'json',
            //url access method type
            mtype: 'POST',
            //columns model
            //columns names
            colNames: ['No Of Banks','Name', 'FullName', 'Description', 'Enabled', 'Tranbase', 'Group ID', 'Email Address', 'Phone', 'Pager', 'Fax', 'Comments', ' '],
            colModel: [
                        //displayed Columns
                        { name: 'BankLinks', index: 'BankLinks', align: 'center', width:40, editable:false },
                        { name: 'LogonName', index: 'LogonName', align: 'left', width:80, editable:true },
                        { name: 'FullName', index: 'FullName', align: 'left', editable:true, width: 200 },
                        { name: 'Description', index: 'Description', align: 'left', width: 200, editable:true, edittype:'textarea'},
                        { name: 'Enabled', index: 'Enabled', align: 'center', width: 60, editable:true},
                        { name: 'IsTranbase', index: 'IsTranbase', align: 'center', width: 60, editable:true, formatter: YesNoFormatter, unformat:YesNoUnformatter, edittype:'checkbox', editoptions:{value:'1:0'}},

                        //Hidden Columns
                        { width: 60,name: 'GroupID', index: 'GroupID', hidden: true, editable:true, editrules:{required:false, edithidden:true} },
                        { width: 60,name: 'Email', index: 'Email', hidden: true, editable:true, editrules:{required:false, edithidden:true}, editype:'email' },
                        { width: 60,name: 'Phone', index: 'Phone', hidden: true, editable:true, editrules:{required:false, edithidden:true, number: true, minValue: 0 }, editype:'text'},
                        { width: 60,name: 'Pager', index: 'Pager', hidden: true, editable:true, editrules:{required:false, edithidden:true, number: true, minValue: 0 }, editype:'text'},
                        { width: 60,name: 'Fax', index: 'Fax', hidden: true, editable:true, editrules:{required:false, edithidden:true, number: true, minValue: 0 }, editype:'text'},
                        { width: 60,name: 'Comments', index: 'Comments', align: 'left', hidden: true, editable:true, edittype:'textarea'},

                        //Action column
                        { name: 'myac', width:80, fixed:true, sortable:false, resize:false, editable:false, formatter:'actions', formatoptions: { 
                                                                                                                    keys:true, 
                                                                                                                    delOptions: { url : encodeURI('@Url.Action("Delete")') } 
                                                                                                                 }
                        }
                      ],
            //pager for grid
            pager: $('#jpgpCustomers'),
            //number of rows per page
            rowNum: 10,
            //initial sorting column
            sortname: 'FullName',
            //initial sorting direction
            sortorder: 'asc',
            //we want to display total records count
            viewrecords: true,
            //grid height
            height: '100%',
            editurl: encodeURI('@Url.Action("Edit")'),
            //subgrid
            subGrid: true,
            //subrid model
            subGridRowExpanded: function(subgrid_id, row_id) {
                var subgrid_table_id, pager_id;
                subgrid_table_id = subgrid_id+"_t";
                pager_id = "p_"+subgrid_table_id;
                $("#"+subgrid_id).html("<table id='"+subgrid_table_id+"' class='scroll'></table><div id='"+pager_id+"' class='scroll'></div>");
                $("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({
                    url: encodeURI('@Url.Action("BankLinks")' + '?id=' + row_id),
                    datatype: 'json',
                    mtype: 'POST',
                    colNames: ['Bank', 'Folder', 'Enabled'],
                    colModel: 
                    [
                        {name:"Bank",index:"Bank",width:20,key:true},
                        {name:"Folder",index:"Folder",width:20},
                        {name:"Enabled",index:"Enabled",width:10,align:"left"}
                    ],
                    rowNum:20,
                    pager: pager_id,
                    sortname: 'Bank',
                    sortorder: "asc",
                    viewrecords: true,
                    height: '100%'
                });
                $("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid('navGrid',"#"+pager_id,{edit:false,add:false,del:false})
            },
        });
        $("#jpgCustomers").jqGrid('navGrid', '#jpgpCustomers', 
                    { add: true, del: true, edit: true, search: false},
                    { width: 'auto', url: '@Url.Action("Edit")'},
                    { width: 'auto', url: '@Url.Action("Edit")' },
                    { width: 'auto', url: '@Url.Action("Delete")' });

    });

    function YesNoFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
        var cellValueInt = parseInt(cellvalue);
        if (cellValueInt == 1)
            return "<img src='@Url.Content("~/Content/images/tick.gif")' title='"+ cellvalue + "' />";
        else 
            return "<img src='@Url.Content("~/Content/images/cross.gif")' title='"+ cellvalue + "' />";
    };

    function YesNoUnformatter (cellvalue, options, cell) {
        return $('img', cell).attr('title');
    };

    </script>
}
```

my controller actions:

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Customers(JqGridRequest request)
    {
        ISession session = NHibernateHelper.GetCurrentSession();
        try
        {
            IEnumerable<Customer> customers = session.QueryOver<Customer>().List().Skip<Customer>(0).Take<Customer>(request.RecordsCount);

            int totalRecords = customers.Count();

            //Prepare JqGridData instance
            JqGridResponse response = new JqGridResponse()
            {
                //Total pages count
                TotalPagesCount = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)request.RecordsCount),
                //Page number
                PageIndex = request.PageIndex,
                //Total records count
                TotalRecordsCount = totalRecords
            };
            //Table with rows data
            foreach (Customer customer in customers)
            {
                response.Records.Add(new JqGridRecord(Convert.ToString(customer.Id), new List<object>()
            {
                customer.Banks.Count(),
                customer.LogonName,
                customer.FullName,
                customer.Description,
                customer.Enabled,
                customer.IsTB,
                customer.GroupID,
                customer.Email,
                customer.Phone,
                customer.Pager,
                customer.Fax,
                customer.Comments
            }));
            }

            //Return data as json
            return new JqGridJsonResult() { Data = response };

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult BankLinks(int Id, JqGridRequest request)
    {
        ISession session = NHibernateHelper.GetCurrentSession();

        Customer customer = session.Get<Customer>(Id);

        int totalRecords = customer.Banks.Count();

        //Prepare JqGridData instance
        JqGridResponse response = new JqGridResponse()
        {
            //Total pages count
            TotalPagesCount = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)request.RecordsCount),
            //Page number
            PageIndex = request.PageIndex,
            //Total records count
            TotalRecordsCount = totalRecords
        };

        foreach (Bank bank in customer.Banks.ToList<Bank>())
        {
            //IEnumerable<CustomerBank> bankLink = session.CreateQuery("from CustomerBank where Bank_ID = :bankId").SetParameter("bankId", bank.Id).List<CustomerBank>();
            CustomerBank bankLink = session.QueryOver<CustomerBank>().Where(x => x.BankId == bank.Id).Where(y => y.CustomerId == customer.Id).List<CustomerBank>().FirstOrDefault();
            //IEnumerable<CustomerBank> bankLink2 = session.QueryOver<CustomerBank>().List<CustomerBank>();

            response.Records.Add(new JqGridRecord(null, new List<object>()
            {
                bank.BankCode,
                bank.Folder,
                bankLink.Enabled 
            }));
        }

        return new JqGridJsonResult() { Data = response };
    }
```

Comment: You should post the full demo project which demonstrate the problem. There are many old tricks to solve the close problem. The solution consist from adding some *additional CSS styles* to solve minor compatibility problems between the default ASP.NET MVC CSS and jqGrid CSS.

Comment: Hi Oleg, thaks foryour reply! I've added the Whole View (index.xshtml) and the controller Actions for that view, what else do you need to know? do you need me to post the ui.jqgrid.css or the Site.css (both unchanged fro The default).

Comment: The problem is typically in `Site.css`. Probably you can just download [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jqGridExportToExcel.zip) from [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9349688/315935), verify that it has no horizontal scroll bar on your computer, compare `Site.css` from the demo with youth and try the same CSS from `Index.aspx` of the demo. The demo don't uses razor, but I hope the `Site.css` is the same. I hope that in the way you will localize and fix your problem.

Comment: OK, I have added downloaded the jqGridDemo, and where I could not get It to load properly, I included the Site.css from it into my project. The width wtill is not being calculated properly, and still cutting off the Last column. very confused!

Comment: I have noticed that div gbox_jpgCustomers has a width='780px' - with no apparent Padding/margin settings, though gview_jpgcustomers also has a width='780px' with padding=0em.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the Answer while looking for Something else (resizing the Page edit box on the navigation bar)

See [Resize the jqGrid page edit box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6283665/resize-the-jqgrid-page-edit-box)

There Are some Stylesheet tweaks in here(for MVC) that Oleg has Added which as well as sorted out the Horizontal Scrollbar issue, also sorted out the Page edit box Sixing issue! - thanks Oleg!